# Question about software-based filters for manipulating already recorded video

Tags: filters, video

"Extant", a recent TV series, involved a female astronaut (played by Halle Berry) who was pregnant with an alien-human hybrid baby when she returned to earth from a space station.

During the first episode Halle Berry saw an old (boy)friend appear at the space station (she was supposed to be alone at the station). This individual was not captured by any of the CCTV cameras inside the space station.

In one of the subsequent episodes, one of Halle Berry's colleagues created a filter (seemingly a script of some sort) on the software that was used to analyze the video feed from the space station. By running this filter on the already recorded video, he was able to remove specific colors from the video and to slow the video down drastically. Consequently they were able to see that the person that had visited Halle was somehow connected to a micro-organism (like fungi) that was not visible to naked eye.

I wanted to ask a couple of questions about this:

1. Would it be technically possible to see features like that on an already recorded video and would this require something from the video hardware as well?
2. Does software exist that allows the manipulation of video through scripts like that?

Comment: Video questions are off-topic here, but feel free to investigate [video.stackexchange.com](http://video.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, that "video" tag mislead me into thinking that I could post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see wavelenghts that were not recorded, no. A security camera might have an IR channel that is not used in the final image in daylight, and scientific cameras may have different channels than those made specifically to model human vision, with processing to approximate a realistic picture (e.g. Hubble telescope pictures), and using the narrow filters in full capability to identify interesting phenomena instead of the "pretty" picture would give effects like that.

Such a multichallel camera would naturally have tools to fiddle with the data.  Suppose there are 17 recorded channels with narrow band filters, polarization, and non-visible wavelengths. Rather than just turningnon a funny channel in false color, software might domwhat photoshop does on stills: combine layers in different ways; then map a palette of false color to resulting data.

For example, any one channel doesn't show anything interesting, but corelating a dip in a narrow red band frequency (found by comparing that narrow band with wide (normal vision) red *and* factoring in the expected spectrum of materials in the view (from nearby pixels, or other frames), with a change in polarization of something else, reveals an image.

Mix with technobabble and season to desired hardness.